# Libgdx. when i exit my game admob is still working

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

i have problem with admob. Admob is working good but when i exit my game admob is still working. What i done wrong ? Please help me.

Even if i exit the game, in the logcat i see that admob is still working.

AndroidLuncher.java

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

private AdView adView;
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
         cfg.useWakelock = true;
         cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
         cfg.useCompass = false;


         // Create the layout
         RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

         // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
         getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

         // Create the libgdx View
         View gameView = initializeForView(new MyGameStart(), cfg);

         // Add the libGDX view
         layout.addView(gameView);

         // Create and setup the AdMob view
         AdView adView = new AdView(this);
         adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
         adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

         AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
         .addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
         .build();

         // Add the AdMob view
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
             new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
         adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

         adView.loadAd(adRequest);
         layout.addView(adView, adParams);

         // Hook it all up
         setContentView(layout);



}
  @Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      if (adView != null) {
        adView.resume();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      if (adView != null) {
        adView.pause();
      }
      super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      // Destroy the AdView.
      if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();

      }
      super.onDestroy();
    } }
```

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.com.test.testgame.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >

         <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="pl.com.test.testgame.android.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>

02-13 14:58:55.271: I/Ads(2604): Starting ad request.
```

02-13 14:58:56.111: I/Ads(2604): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
02-13 14:58:56.111: I/Ads(2604): Ad finished loading.

EXIT GAME

02-13 14:59:56.121: I/Ads(2604): Starting ad request.
02-13 14:59:56.931: I/Ads(2604): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
02-13 14:59:56.931: I/Ads(2604): Ad finished loading.

Comment: You mentioned that you see in the logs that AdMob is still running.  Can you post those logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I had two times Adview adview;

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                       ***

         // Create and setup the AdMob view
         AdView adView = new AdView(this);

                       ***
```

When I removed one, AdMob is working correctly.

Comment: Please mark this as correct then so we know this has been "solved".

Comment: When i click "accept this answer... " i get "you can accept your own answer tommorow" sorry but i cant mark this solved ;/

Answer (score 0):

Create an onStop() method and stop adMob there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the AdView instance to NULL and leave it there for the GC to handle it. It probably will trow a NullPointerException so make sure you handle that.